# Changing the frequency of Heroku Metrics Logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

As described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics), Heroku logs metrics for your dynos every ~20 seconds.

```
source=web.1 dyno=heroku.2808254.d97d0ea7-cf3d-411b-b453-d2943a50b456 sample#load_avg_1m=2.46 sample#load_avg_5m=1.06 sample#load_avg_15m=0.99
source=web.1 dyno=heroku.2808254.d97d0ea7-cf3d-411b-b453-d2943a50b456 sample#memory_total=21.00MB sample#memory_rss=21.22MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=348836pages sample#memory_pgpgout=343403pages
```

These pile up quickly and distract from the log view, especially when they are every 20 seconds and there are 10+ dynos for a small web app.

Is it possible to change the frequency at which these are logged? Something like once per minute would cut the quantity down by a factor of 3 and would still be sufficient for my app's needs.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Heroku does [provide a way of filter out certain types of logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#types-of-logs) while tailing, so in theory I could get rid of them entirely by excluding the system logs. But if there are other valuable things in the system logs, the question of how to specifically reduce (not filter out) these metrics still stands.

Comment: No, that it not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem and decided to just turn off the runtime-metrics logging altogether.

You can check to see if it's enabled with:

```
$ heroku labs -a you-app-name

 === App Features (your-app-name)
[+] log-runtime-metrics    Emit dyno resource usage information into app logs
```

and remove it with

```
heroku labs:disable log-runtime-metrics -a your-app-name
heroku restart -a your-app-name
```